# What is the syntax of a complex condition in shell?

Tags: shell

If want to express the following test in shell (sh) :

```
if ( a == 1 && ( b == 1 || b == 2 )) { ... }
```

So far, the best I have been able to write is this :

```
if [[ $a -eq 1 ]]; then
  if [[ $b -eq 1 || $b -eq 2 ]]; then
     ...
  fi
fi
```

I don't know how to compound && and || with correct precedence. Googling has not given me any answer (tutorials only give basic examples, if any)

What is the syntax to combine those two *if* into one ?

Comment: Any reason to not use `ksh`? Then your initial code would require only one more pair of parenthesis: `if (( a == 1 && ( b == 1 || b == 2 ))); then :; fi`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that `[[ ]]` is not in either Bourne or POSIX `sh`.  For true `sh` syntax, there are several ways to do this.

**Using only one `[ ]` pair**

```
if [ 1 -eq "$a" -a \( 1 -eq "$b" -o 2 -eq "$b" \) ]; then
    # ...
fi
```

or **Avoiding the POSIX `-a` and `-o` options**<sup>1</sup>

```
if [ 1 -eq "$a" ] && { [ 1 -eq "$b" ] || [ 2 -eq "$b" ]; }; then
    # ...
fi
```

<sup>1</sup> One reason for avoiding `-a` and `-o` is maximum portability - not all `test` or `[` implementations can handle more than 4 arguments, which is precisely what you get if you chain expressions with `-a` and `-o` and `\( \)`.

Comment: My scripts have the _#! /bin/sh_ shebang, and the default shell is _ksh_. Why would sh not be used ?

Comment: @Offirmo If you declare your script as `/bin/sh`, it is incorrect to write the script using features not in `sh`.  You should be aware that `ksh` is NOT `sh`, but rather a superset of `sh`.  If you take your `ksh`-but-declared-as-`sh` script to a system where `sh` is not a symlink to `ksh`, it may break.  You can avoid that problem by making sure your script matches the declaration.

Comment: I thought that setting _/bin/sh_ as shebang would make my scripts invoked via _/bin/sh_. Do you mean that my default shell (ksh) ignore the shebang and interpret it directly ?

Comment: @Offirmo You are correct: a shebang of `/bin/sh` will invoke `/bin/sh`.  The problem is `/bin/sh` does not accept `[[`.  You can either not use `[[` or use a shell that does accept `[[`, e.g. `ksh`, as your shebang.

Comment: That's puzzling... my shebang are all _/bin/sh_ and I use [[ ]] everywhere and it works... Must be some strange config on my RedHat 5... Found it ! _/bin/sh_ is a symbolic link pointing to _/bin/bash_ on my machine. I'll update my shebangs accordingly. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Offirmo Exactly - the point is bare `/bin/sh` does not have `[[`, and you can't rely on `sh` being a symlink to `bash` everywhere.

Comment: @jw013, `/bin/sh` will be an interpreter for the `sh` language (either Bourne-sh language or POSIX-sh language depending on the system). None of those `sh` languages have `[[`, but the `/bin/sh` interpreter may support it as an extension on some systems (like RHEL5 where `/bin/sh` is actually `bash`). Either way, `[[` should not be used where the she-bang is `sh`, though it may still work.

Comment: The problem is not that much that `-a`/`-o` are not supported by some implementations but that  it's not reliable for arbitrary arguments. Like `[ "$a" = "$b" -o "$b" = "$c" ]` would fail for values of `$a` like `!` with many `[` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I tried some syntax and found that

```
if [[ $a -eq 1 ]] && [[ $b -eq 1 || $b -eq 2 ]]; then
 ...
fi
```

is working.

Comment: this works for bash version above 4.

Answer (score 2):

Another POSIX approach:

```
if [ "$((a == 1 && ( b == 1 || b == 2 )))" -ne 0 ]; then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it with a mere `shell`:

```
if test 1 -eq "$a" && test 1 -eq "$b" -o 2 -eq "$b"; then 
    ...
fi
```

Explanation:

`test` here serves as parenthesis and `-o` as logical or. If you a logical and inside the "parenthesis" you would use `-a`.

More on that can be found [here](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch03sec02.html)